# How to set dynamic id with getElementById with c# variable

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to use the `document.getElementById` with a dynamic variable.

The dynamic variable will be set based on a query string that is read in from the code behind (c#) in the URL.

So for example, this would be the ideal way it works:

**c# code behind:**

```
string myVar = Request.QueryString[0];
myVar = myVar + "Link";
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
    document.getElementById(myVar)
</script>
```

Any idea on how to get this to work?

Comment: And then what? What exactly is your question here?  BTW: `var` is a Javascript keyword - change it to `myVar`, or something meaningful.

Comment: I updated my question to make what I'm asking more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply insert this in a script block on your .aspx page (note, avoid using "var" as the name, as that is a reserved word in Javascript):

```
<script>
    var id = '<%= HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Request.QueryString[0]) + "something" %>';
    document.getElementById(id);
</script>
```

You could inject it into the page from code behind by using [`RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx):

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "QueryId", 
    string.Format("<script>var id='{0}';</script>", 
        HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Request.QueryString[0]) + "something"
    )
);
```

Comment: One must always escape user's input. Try <%= HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Request.QueryString[0]) %>

Comment: Awesome I'll give this a try and mark it correctly after I test it! That's way easier than I thought it'd be.

Comment: Sorry, one question. I updated my original question but I just realized in my code I'm actually trying to add another string to what I get from the queryString before using it as a ID. Is this possible? If not no biggie I can adapt my code to use this solution! Thanks!

Comment: Because the query string parameter is being embedded inside a JavaScript string literal, not inside HTML, you must use JavaScriptStringEncode (with the second parameter set to false) instead of HtmlEncode to avoid an injection vulnerability.

Comment: awesome thanks! I haven't gotten to testing yet but once I have I'll mark the answer as the correct one!

Comment: I went ahead and used your first answer, where the var is declared in the script directly. I tried to put the c# code in my Page_Load but it didn't seem to work. On a side note, is there a way to make sure the user's input is being handled to avoid injection? I entered <hello> as a input while using JavaScriptStringEncode and HTMLEncode and in debug mode at least, ASP just gives me this warning: A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client. Does this mean it's being handled?

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that you cannot just communicate with Server-Side using JS, JS is a client side, so you won't get the variables that you created in ServerSide.

To get them, you'll require:

```
<%= write_the_thing_here %>
```

For your code, you'll write:

```
string someThing = "<%= HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Request.QueryString[0]) %>";
// now use this someThing in the document..you can use var instead of string
// but not them both..
document.getElementById(someThing); 
// note the semicolon on the end, to close it..
```

You should not use `string var` because they are the data types in JavaScript as well as ASP.NET, so code might get puzzled thinking what the hell is this.

Instead of this, you can also try to write a hidden input field as

```
<input type="hidden" name="someThing" value="@Request.QueryString[0]" />
```

Then use it to do what ever you want to do dynamically. This might be the easy way of doing this, if you really want to use the ID from the server.

Sorry about the jQuery buddy:

```
var someThinge = $('input[type="hidden"]').val();
```

And then, continue your work!

Help note by **Alexei Levenkov**: semicolons in JavaScript are optional. They main use is to distinguish if code written by obfuscators/minimizers (tools or people) or normal developers :)

Comment: Side note: semicolons in JavaScript are optional. They main use is to distinguish if code written by obfuscators/minimizers (tools or people) or normal developers :). Also as @mike commented on other answer - you have script injection in your sample, which is not a good practice.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  there you go buddy :) i have updated the answer, is there any other error ? :)